# Spring Boot | LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods Exception

Tags: java, rest, maven, spring-boot, client

I have a simple spring boot app that I'm using to connect to a REST api and see it response. It's a simple app for prototyping. However I'm getting the following errors:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:874) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:969) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:233) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:178) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.createChildManagementContext(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:193) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.afterSingletonsInstantiated(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:156) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:779) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at com.crossover.techtrial.java.se.TrialApplication.main(TrialApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]

2017-05-15 22:17:45.906 ERROR 5488 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9001]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9001]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:233) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:178) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.createChildManagementContext(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:193) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.afterSingletonsInstantiated(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:156) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:779) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at com.crossover.techtrial.java.se.TrialApplication.main(TrialApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:976) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:874) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:969) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

2017-05-15 22:17:45.912  INFO 5488 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-05-15 22:17:45.919  INFO 5488 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-05-15 22:17:45.930  INFO 5488 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-05-15 22:17:45.931  INFO 5488 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4228f269: startup date [Mon May 15 22:17:45 PKT 2017]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@61df66b6
2017-05-15 22:17:45.934 ERROR 5488 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 9001 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 9001, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2017-05-15 22:17:45.935  INFO 5488 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@61df66b6: startup date [Mon May 15 22:17:42 PKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-15 22:17:45.935  WARN 5488 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@61df66b6: startup date [Mon May 15 22:17:42 PKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:818) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at com.crossover.techtrial.java.se.TrialApplication.main(TrialApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]

2017-05-15 22:17:45.936  INFO 5488 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-05-15 22:17:45.936  INFO 5488 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

I'm guessing java.net.BindException is throwing because of port 9001 but this is the same port I configured Actuator to run on and it was running fine before adding the client functionality. I don't understand why is it throwing this exception because I thought it will always restart the container when I run my app as a standalone app.

The rest of the exceptions I have no clue why are occurring. After searching on net I found that it may be because of conflicting dependencies however I can't see any in my pom.xml.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.crossover.techtrial.java.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>trial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>trial</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SampleDB
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
management.port = 9001
apiforest.baseuri = https://api-forest/....
read.timeout = 10000
connect.timeout = 10000
```

My code for Account DTO:

```
package com.crossover.techtrial.java.se.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Account 
{
    private String id;

    private MonetaryAmount monetaryAmount;

    public Account()
    {

    }

    public String getId() 
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) 
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public  MonetaryAmount getMonetaryAmount() 
    {
        return monetaryAmount;
    }

    public void setMonetaryAmount(MonetaryAmount monetaryAmount) 
    {
        this.monetaryAmount = monetaryAmount;
    }

}
```

My calling code:

```
package com.crossover.techtrial.java.se;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.crossover.techtrial.java.se.dto.Account;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TrialApplicationTests 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Account[] accounts = restTemplate.getForObject("${apiforest.baseuri}" + "/pay/accounts", Account[].class);
        System.out.println(accounts);
    }*/


    @Test
    public void contextLoads() 
    {
    }

}
```

My RestConfig class:

```
package com.crossover.techtrial.java.se.config;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

// To set the configuration parameters like read timeout and connect timeout for Rest Client
@Configuration
public class RestConfig 
{
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate createRestTemplate(final ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory)
    {
        return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientHttpRequestFactory createClientHttpRequestFactory(@Value("${connect.timeout}") final int connectTimeout,
            @Value("${read.timeout}") final int readTimeout)
    {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
        factory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Please help me in resolving this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `netstat` (on both linux and windows) to check which application is listening on that port (netstat can also tell you the name of the executable). It is possible you either have a rogue program, or you have a hanged instance of your test app.

Comment: I did that. Nothing is running at that port. I'm fairly confident it has to do with my app since I ran it one time to test if I configured everything properly without writing any code. My problem is why am I getting this error since it runs as a standalone app and I can't see it even in my task manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny enough today when I ran my app, it didn't give me that error. I don't know what caused it but seems like rebooting the PC fixed it.

Comment: The port on which you are trying to start your application was being used by some other process. You have to kill the process running on that port and then start application. Restarting your pc did the work because it killed the process on the port.

Answer (score 6):

The port which your application was supposed to use was already used by other application.When you rebooted your PC application which was using the port got terminated and port got free. That is the reason your application ran after reboot.

you can check the port number and pid of process using the command **netstat -nao** on windows.